# Read hive table in oozie mapreduce action

Tags: hive, oozie

I have a workflow, in which an oozie mapreduce action is supposed to read data from hive table and give it to appropriate mapper. I have not been able to find corresponding settings/properties for workflow.

Answer (score 1):

The data of the hive table is stored in a folder, why don't you read it from there?

`create table t01 (line String) STORED AS TextFile LOCATION "pathToStoredFile";`